# [OpenLayer]: Marker not appearing over Image Layer

Tags: openlayers

I have used OpenLayers.Layer.Image to show our own .PNG image in my map.

Also, to show marker over this .PNG image I have used OpenLayers.Layer.Markers layer.

Following is my code:

```
imageLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Image("Image Raster","http://www.texturewarehouse.com/gallery/photos/21/thb_1215634405-21.jpg", bounds,new OpenLayers.Size(500,500),{isBaseLayer:true});


markersLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.Markers("Markers");
map = new OpenLayers.Map('map');
map.addLayer(markersLayer);
map.addLayer(imageLayer);
map.setCenter(new OpenLayers.LonLat(1,1).transform(                                               new OpenLayers.Projection("EPSG:4326"),                                               map.getProjectionObject()));

var location = new OpenLayers.LonLat(90,20);
var size = new OpenLayers.Size(25,35);
var offset = new OpenLayers.Pixel(90, 23);
var icon = new   OpenLayers.Icon('http://www.openlayers.org/dev/img/marker.png',size,offset);

markersLayer.addMarker(new OpenLayers.Marker(location,icon.clone()));
```

Issue is this that marker doesn't appear over the .PNG image...it seems image layer hides markers layer....struggling to fix this but no solution....please help me as I have to deliver this on Monday....thanks a lot in advance,

Gajendra

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your example and not faced with described problem. All works fine with little modification. See my source code: http://pastie.org/3669443